# Haskell: What are the types of these expressions (if they have any)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to haskell and I am doing some exercises to learn as much as I can about types, but some of the questions are really confusing to me. The exercise I'm struggling with reads:

What are the types of the following expressions? If the expression has no type, do state as much. Also
be sure to declare necessary class restrictions where needed.

```
5 + 8 :: ?
(+) 2 :: ?
(+2) :: ?
(2+) :: ?
```

I get that 5 + 8 will return an Int, but the others are not valid expressions by them selves. Does that mean that they have no type, or should i think of them as functions (f :: Int -> Int)(f x = x + 2)?

Comment: Why not just ask GHCi? You can write `:type` (or `:t` for short) followed by the expression, and it will tell you the type.

Comment: "*the others are not valid expressions by them selves*" - actually, they are. That might be what the exercise wants you to learn. "*should i think of them as functions*" - yes, that's exactly how they work.

Comment: Take a look at the *Section of an infix operator*: https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the answers:

- `5 + 8` has the type `forall a. Num a => a` which can be specialized to `Int`.
- `(+) 2` and `(2 +)` are the same and both have the type `forall a. Num a => a -> a` which can be specialized to `Int -> Int`.
- `(+ 2)` is different but also has the type `forall a. Num a => a -> a` which can be specialized to `Int -> Int`.
- `(+)` has the type `forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a` which can be specialized to `Int -> Int -> Int`.

For further explanation, read on.

---

### One Literal, Many Types

In Haskell, a numeric literal like `114514` does *not* have a concrete type like `Int`. This is good because we have many different types for numbers, incl. `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` and so on, and we do not want to have different notations for each type.

The literals `5`, `114514`, and `1919810` all have the type

```
forall a. Num a => a
```

You can read it like this: "for any type `a`, if `a` is an instance of the `Num` **typeclass**, then the value can have the type `a`." `Int`, `Integer`, `Float` and `Double` are all instances of `Num`, and because Haskell has (relatively) strong type inference, in different contexts it will be specialized to concrete types like `Int`.

So what is typeclass?

### Typeclasses

The way we express some type "supports" some operation(s) in Haskell is by *typeclasses*. A typeclass is a set of function *signatures*, without real implementations. They represent operations we want to make on some types (e.g. `Num` represents operations we want to make on numeric types), but the actual implementations on different types may differ (the actual calculation of integers and floating point numbers are *really* different).

We can make a type be an `instance` of a typeclass (note that this has *nothing* to do with the instances and classes in object-oriented programming), by actually *defining* these functions for this type. In this way, we defined this type to support these operations.

`Num` is one of the typeclasses, which represents the support of numeric operations. It is partially defined as below (I did not put the full one here, in order to reduce verbosity):

```
class Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
    (-) :: a -> a -> a
    (*) :: a -> a -> a
```

You can see that in the signatures we have `a`s instead of real concrete types, these functions are said to be *polymorphic*, that is, they are generic and can be specialized to different types.

For example, if `a` and `b` are both `Int`s, then `a + b` has type `Int` too, because haskell inferred that the `+` we used here should be the one defined for `Int`, given that both of its arguments are `Int`s.

So, if some type is an instance of `Num`, it means that the `+`, `-` and `*` operator is defined for this type. Being an instance of `Num` means supporting these operators.

---

### Sections

One good thing of Haskell is its (relatively) flexible *infix operators*. In Haskell, infix operators are nothing but normal functions with an infix notation (which is merely a syntactic sugar). We can also use infix operators in a prefix manner. For example, `5 + 8` is equivalent to `(+) 5 8`.

It seems that you are confused with `(+) 5`, `(+5)` and `(5+)`. Remember that if we put parentheses on both sides of an infix function, we make it prefix. And as you may already know, prefix functions can be *partially applied*, that is, give the function only some of its parameters, so it becomes a functions with less parameters to be given later. `(+) 5` means that we partially applied `(+)` by only giving its first argument, so it becomes a function waiting for another *one* argument, or originally its second argument. We can apply `(+) 5` to `8` so it becomes `((+) 5) 8`, which is equivalent to `5 + 8`.

On the other hand, `(5+)` and `(+5)` are called *sections*, which are another syntactic sugar for infix operators. `(5+)` means you filled the left hand side of the operator, and it becomes a function waiting for its right hand side. `(5+) 8` means `5 + 8` or `(+) 5 8`. `(+5)` is flipped, i.e. you filled the right hand side, so it is a function waiting for the left hand side. `(+5) 8` means `8 + 5` or `(+) 8 5`.

---

Haskell is a language very different from other languages you may have learned; every expression that compiles has a type. Functions are first-class and every function has a type too. Thinking in types will really help in your learning progress.

Comment: This is a great, informative answer with lots of information, thank you.  However, in the future, for questions about learning the language fundamentals, I would recommend against the "first, the answers" part. It is better to provide the necessary information, which you have definitely done, but let the OP themself make the final leap of synthesizing it to answer their exercise.  Brains are lazy -- they can convince themselves they understand when they don't -- you have to set up the right conditions to make them work, which is when they *really* learn.  Thanks again for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell:

- operators are just functions
- functions can be provided less arguments then declaration
- parenthesis can be used to disambiguate order and components of arguments

Taken together it means that:

- (+) Is just + function, and will take 2 more arguments
- (1 +) Is function with it's first argument provided and will take one more
- (+ 2) Is another function that have is argument provided, but this time second one. It also awaits one more argument